# console log shows old value even after updating it inside .then method in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, es6-promise

I am new to React and JS. So the scenario is as follows. I have a function Component like below.

```
const testComponent = () =>{
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState('INITIAL_VALUE')

    const updateState = async () => {
        setMyState("UPDATED_VALUE")
        console.log('updated using hook')
        console.log(myState)

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        updateState().then(
            () => console.log(myState)
        )
    })

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>
                {myState}
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

All the console.log above logs "INITIAL_VALUE", although they all are called after updating the state variable! I was expecting it to be "UPDATED_VALUE" as it is rendered in HTML dom!  Why do I still get the old value?

Shouldn't it be logging updated value, since it is executed after a promise inside .then() method? As far as I have understood it is .then() methods are executed once the promise is resolved. But this looks pretty strange! Correct me If am wrong!

Comment: try `console.log( JSON.stringify(myState))`

Comment: It may be a typo but your component starts with a lower case letter, React should complain about it and suggest you to make it uppercase like so `TextComponent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `updateState()` resolves, the `myState` variable is updated.
But it's new value will only be displayed/logged on next render.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `myState` inside `useEffect`, you need to add it to your array of dependencies.

This:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 console.log(myState)
},[myState])
```

Should show you the correct results.

Remember to do it in a separate `useEffect` call, though: if you call `updateState` in the same `useEffect` block that has `myState` in the dependencies array, you will get stuck in a sort of infinite loop.

More info in the docs:

```
If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect will always have their initial values.
```

(from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you do not need to use async function for changing your state only.

```
 const testComponent = () =>{
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState('INITIAL_VALUE')

    const updateState = useCallback((value) => {
        setMyState(value);
        console.log('updated using hook')
        console.log(myState)
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      updateState("UPDATED_VALUE");
    }, [])

    console.log(myState); *// would show always the most actual data stored in your **myState** after useEffect finished*

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>
                {myState}
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```